Video Frame-by-Frame Deraining with MFDNet
After checking the repository of MFDNet, single image rain streaks removal with the provided model is given in test.py. I am trying to modify the code to process frame-by-frame rain streaks removal in a video. In other words, the modified code can perform rain streaks removal process in each frame in the given video. FFmpeg package is used in this code. Please check the code and all suggestions are welcome.
import os
import argparse
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import utils
from data_RGB import get_test_data
from MFDNet import HPCNet as mfdnet
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np

def process_video_frame_by_frame(input_file, output_file, model_restoration):
    """
    Decodes a video frame by frame, processes each frame,
    and re-encodes to a new video.

    Args:
        input_file: Path to the input video file.
        output_file: Path to the output video file.
    """
    try:
        # Probe for video information
        probe = ffmpeg.probe(input_file)
        video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
        width = int(video_stream['width'])
        height = int(video_stream['height'])

        # Input
        process1 = (
            ffmpeg
            .input(input_file)
            .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
            .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
        )

        # Output
        process2 = (
            ffmpeg
            .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
            .output(output_file, vcodec='libx264', pix_fmt='yuv420p')
            .overwrite_output()
            .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
        )

        while True:
            # Read a frame
            in_bytes = process1.stdout.read(width * height * 3)
            if not in_bytes:
                break
            in_frame = (
                np
                .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
                .reshape([1, 3, width, height])
            )

            # Process frame (deraining processing)
            in_frame = in_frame / 255
            restored = model_restoration(torch.tensor(in_frame.astype(np.float32)).to(device='cuda'))
            restored = torch.clamp(restored[0], 0, 1)
            restored = restored.cpu().detach().numpy()
            restored *= 255
            out_frame = restored
            np.reshape(out_frame, (3, width, height))

            # Encode and write the frame
            process2.stdin.write(
                out_frame
                .astype(np.uint8)
                .tobytes()
            )

        # Close streams
        process1.stdout.close()
        process2.stdin.close()
        process1.wait()
        process2.wait()

    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        print('stdout:', e.stdout.decode('utf8'))
        print('stderr:', e.stderr.decode('utf8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Image Deraining using MPRNet')

    parser.add_argument('--weights', default='./checkpoints/checkpoints_mfd.pth', type=str,  # './tip_rebuttal_checkpoints/MFD_loss4_latest420.pth'
                        help='Path to weights')
    parser.add_argument('--gpus', default='0', type=str, help='CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = args.gpus

    model_restoration = mfdnet()
    utils.load_checkpoint(model_restoration, args.weights)
    print("===>Testing using weights: ", args.weights)

    # model_restoration.cuda()
    # model_restoration.eval()
    # model_restoration.to(device)
    model_restoration.eval().cuda()
    
    input_video = 'input_video.mp4'
    output_video = 'output_video.mp4'

    process_video_frame_by_frame(input_video, output_video, model_restoration)


I don't really see the need to use numpy as a buffer between ffmpeg and torch as torch.frombuffer and torch.save should be plenty enough for this job as well.
Hence I suggest replacing the while loop with:
while in_bytes := process1.stdout.read(width * height * 3):
    in_frame = torch.frombuffer(in_bytes, dtype=torch.uint8).float().reshape((1, 3, width, height))
    restored = model_restoration(torch.div(in_frame, 255).to(device='cuda'))
    out_frame = torch.mul(restored.cpu().detach(), 255).reshape(3, width, height).byte()
    torch.save(out_frame, process2.stdin)


It's weird that "torch.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory." error happened with this version of code. Do you have any idea about the reason of it?

@JimmyHu I have barely any experience with CUDA, so I don't know. But you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129812/how-to-avoid-cuda-out-of-memory-in-pytorch

Documentation
It is great that you have a docstring describing the function.
It would be good to add a description of the model_restoration
argument to the doctring, as you have done for the other args.
The word "process" is vague.  Consider adding a more precise
description of what the code is doing when it processes video frames.
Comments
Many of the comments in the code are helpful and well-placed.
Here are some suggestions.
Remove the comment at the end of this long line:
parser.add_argument('--weights', default='./checkpoints/checkpoints_mfd.pth', type=str,  # './tip_rebuttal_checkpoints/MFD_loss4_latest420.pth'

Long lines are hard to understand and maintain, and the comment does not
help us understand the code.
Remove the commented-out code:
# model_restoration.cuda()
# model_restoration.eval()
# model_restoration.to(device)

Simpler
There does not seem to be a need for both of these variables:
        out_frame = restored

The code might be simpler and more efficient to just have one variable.
fstring
Consider using an fstring
in place of the format call:
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))

isort
"isort your imports, so you don't have to."
